# I am getting a free(): double free detected in tcache2 when running a gtest on a linked list

Tags: c++

I am trying to complete an assignment for my class and I can figure out where the error is being cause. If anyone can find the problem I would be very appreciative. When i was trying to find the error, all the adds would go through and it seems like the error happens at the resolution of the test. That's the most information I have.

```
template<typename K, typename V>
LinkedListCollection<K,V>::LinkedListCollection() {
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    length = 0;
}

template<typename K, typename V>
LinkedListCollection<K,V>::LinkedListCollection(const LinkedListCollection<K,V>& rhs) {
    Node* cur = head;
    Node* iterator = rhs.head;
    cur = new Node;
    for(int i = 0; i < rhs.size(); i++) {
        cur->key = iterator->key;
        cur->value = iterator->value;
        cur->next = new Node;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    cur->key = rhs.tail->key;
    cur->value = rhs.tail->value;
    tail = cur;
    cur = nullptr;
}

template<typename K, typename V>
LinkedListCollection<K,V>& LinkedListCollection<K,V>::operator=(const LinkedListCollection<K,V>& rhs) {
    make_empty();
    Node* cur = head;
    Node* rhs_cur = rhs.head;
    cur = new Node;
    for(int i = 0; i < rhs.size(); i++) {
        cur->key = rhs_cur->key;
        cur->value = rhs_cur->value;
        cur->next = new Node;
        cur = cur->next;
        rhs_cur = rhs_cur->next;
    }
    cur->key = rhs_cur->key;
    cur->value = rhs_cur->value;
    tail = cur;
}

template<typename K, typename V>
LinkedListCollection<K,V>::~LinkedListCollection() {
    make_empty();
}

template<typename K, typename V>
void LinkedListCollection<K,V>::add(const K& a_key, const V& a_val) {
    if(length == 0) {
        tail = new Node;
        tail->key = a_key;
        tail->value = a_val;
        tail->next = nullptr;
        head = tail;
        length++;
    }
    else {
        tail->next = new Node;
        tail->next->key = a_key;
        tail->next->value = a_val;
        tail->next->next = nullptr;
        tail = tail->next;
        length++;
    }
}

template<typename K, typename V>
void LinkedListCollection<K,V>::remove(const K& a_key) {
    Node* cur = head;
    if(head->key == a_key) {
        cur = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = cur;
        length--;
    }
    if(a_key == tail->key) {
        while(cur->next != tail)
            cur = cur->next;
        delete tail;
        tail = cur;
        length--;
    }
    else {
        if(cur->next != tail) {
            while(cur->next->key != a_key)
                cur = cur->next;
            Node* second = cur->next->next;
            delete cur->next;
            cur = second;
            length--;
        }
    }
}

template<typename K, typename V>
bool LinkedListCollection<K,V>::find(const K& search_key, V& the_val) const {
    Node* cur = head;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(cur->key == search_key) {
            the_val = cur->value;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template<typename K, typename V>
void LinkedListCollection<K,V>::find(const K& k1, const K& k2, std::vector<V>& vals) const {
    Node* cur = head;
    while(cur->key != k1)
        cur = cur->next;
    while(cur->key != k2) {
        vals.push_back(cur->value);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    vals.push_back(cur->value);
}

template<typename K, typename V>
void LinkedListCollection<K,V>::keys(std::vector<K>& all_keys) const {
    Node* cur = head;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        all_keys.push_back(cur->key);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

template<typename K, typename V>
void LinkedListCollection<K,V>::sort(std::vector<K>& all_keys_sorted) const {
    Node* cur = head;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        all_keys_sorted.push_back(cur->key);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    std::sort(all_keys_sorted.begin(), all_keys_sorted.end());
}

template<typename K, typename V>
int LinkedListCollection<K,V>::size() const {
    return length;
}

template<typename K, typename V>
void LinkedListCollection<K,V>::make_empty() {
    while(head) {
        Node* cur = head;
        while(cur->next) 
            cur = cur->next;
        delete cur;
    }
}


#endif
```

This is the test I run

```
TEST(BasicListTest, CorrectSize) {
  LinkedListCollection<string,double> c;
  ASSERT_EQ(0, c.size());
  c.add("b", 10.0);
  ASSERT_EQ(1, c.size());
  c.add("a", 20.0);
  ASSERT_EQ(2, c.size());
  c.add("c", 20.0);
  ASSERT_EQ(3, c.size());
}
```

The message I get after is

free(): double free detected in tcache2

Comment: You're probably trying to free the same pointer multiple times.  Did you use `valgrind` or compile with the address sanitizer enabled?  Either would probably narrow this down real fast.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at our [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with special attention to the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You haven't given us enough code to reproduce the error, but at a glance I see that your last function, `make_empty()`, doesn't do what you intend.

Comment: When the error happens at the end of a block, like your test function, the bug is in a destructor. That's where to look first.

Answer (score -1):

I bet your bug is in here:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
void LinkedListCollection<K,V>::make_empty() {
    while(head) {
        Node* cur = head;
        while(cur->next) 
            cur = cur->next;
        delete cur;
    }
}
```

I think it should look like this (but I didn't test it):

```
template<typename K, typename V>
void LinkedListCollection<K,V>::make_empty() {
    Node* cur = head;
    while(cur) {
        Node* tmp = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You *definitely* didn't test it.

Comment: You didn't test that one either.

Comment: @Beta and I'm not going to, but what do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: not worth the time to figure it out, all these linked list questions from classes, you'd think they'd have a TA to ask questions from, or the teacher.

Comment: If you don't think it's worth it than you shouldn't do it. We need to be discouraging questions like this and a big part is not offering answers unless there is a half way ok question.

Comment: @DerekC. This one at least seems to have complete code.